# Jest shows undefined when error is thrown from my controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, tdd

I have a Node controller to test with Jest, my aim is to test if user has already a Stripe subscription:

**`controllers/userSubscriptionController.js`**

```js
const userSubscription = async (req, res, next) => {
    const trowErr = true;
    if(throwErr){
       throw new Error("User has already subscribed.");
    }
}
module.exports = {userSubscription}
```

**`controllers/__tests__/userSubscriptionController.js`**

```js
const {userSubscription} = require('../controllers/userSubscriptionController');
const { mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext } = require("./interceptor");
let req = mockRequest();
let res = mockResponse();
let next = mockNext();
describe("My first test", async () => {
    it("should throws an error", () => {
        const s = await userSubscription(req, res, next)
        expect(s).toThrow()
    })
})
```

So when launching the test I received:

```
expect(received).toThrow(), Matcher error: received value must be a function , Received has value: undefined**
```

Why received has an undefined value that makes the test fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test when the `userSubscription` throws no value is assigned to the `const s` so it's undefined.

To test your `async` function you can write the test like this

```
 describe('using returned promise', () => {
    it("should throws an error", () => {
      return expect(userSubscription(req, res, next)).rejects.toThrow('User has already subscribed')
    })
  })
```

or like this:

```
  describe('using await', () => {
    it("should throws an error", async () => {
      await expect(userSubscription(req, res, next)).rejects.toThrow('User has already subscribed')
    })
  })
```

https://repl.it/repls/AgreeableSlipperyHacks